# pg_dumpall, how do you specify a different cluster

Tags: postgresql

running pg_dumpall makes a backup of the cluster "main", but I have another cluster "custom". How do I make pg_dumpall produce a backup of "custom"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every cluster is served by a different Postgres instance, listening on different port and/or using different unix domain socket (if there are different instances running on one machine).

So you need to pass different value for the [port](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-dumpall.html):

```
-p port
--port=port

    Specifies the TCP port or local Unix domain socket file extension on which the server is listening for connections. Defaults to the PGPORT environment variable, if set, or a compiled-in default.
```

Comment: The default value of the port for a given cluster can be found in the postgresql.conf file in the cluster folder.